# Determining how far away is the next ID

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datediff

So I have some data, subset as follows:

```
ID  data start_time 
001    X 2021-12-29 10:54:12.429 +0000
002    Y 2022-01-16 05:07:55.708 +0000 
003    Y 2021-12-31 12:25:12.980 +0000
002    A 2022-01-03 12:49:41.866 +0000
001    A 2021-12-30 16:32:13.736 +0000
001    A 2022-01-17 10:10:10.736 +0000
```

I would like to determine in minutes, the time difference between a given `ID` and **the next occurrence** in the dataframe, in order of `start_time`. So if an `ID` appears at 12:00 and 12:01, I would like the `ID` to show the time of the next entry as well as the diff in minutes, using SQL/Snowflake. CTE preferred.

The following fields should be added:

- `next_timestamp`: The timestamp of the following entry
- `time_diff`: The difference *in minutes* between `start_time` and `next_timestamp`.
- `entry_order`: The number of how many of this `ID` has been.

**Expected output:**

```
ID  data start_time                       next_timestamp                 time_diff  entry_order
001    X 2021-12-29 10:54:12.429 +0000    2021-12-30 16:32:13.736 +0000  1778       1
001    A 2021-12-30 16:32:13.736 +0000    2022-01-17 10:10:10.736 +0000  25537      2
003    Y 2021-12-31 12:25:12.980 +0000    NULL                           NULL       1
002    A 2022-01-03 12:49:41.866 +0000    2022-01-16 05:07:55.708 +0000  18258      1
002    Y 2022-01-16 05:07:55.708 +0000    NULL                           NULL       2
001    A 2022-01-17 10:10:10.736 +0000    NULL                           NULL       3
```

Notice, the resulting output is ordered by the timestamp, ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LEAD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lead.html) function can be used to find the next start_time per ID.

And the [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) function can return a unique sequencial number per ID.

```
SELECT *
, LEAD(start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_time) AS next_timestamp
, DATEDIFF(minute, start_time, LEAD(start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_time)) AS time_diff
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_time) AS entry_order
FROM your_table
ORDER BY start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `LEAD`, `DATEDIFF` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *,
   LEAD(start_time) OVER(PARTITITON BY ID ORDER BY start_time) AS next_timestamp,
   DATEDIFF(seconds, start_time, next_timestamp) SA time_difference,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITITON BY ID ORDER BY start_time) AS entry_order
FROM tab
```